# mySQL syntax with OR

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have problem with syntax in MySQL query. I am using Symfony2 where I am trying to filter knownUsers by function

```
protected function generateAlias($tag = null)
{
    return '___' . $tag . '_' . $this->aliasCounter++;
}    



public function filterKnownUsers(\Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\User $user, $addMyUser = false)
    {
        $alias = $this->generateAlias();

        $query = "SELECT {$alias}_u2.userId FROM Tuxie\\Bundle\\TuxieBundle\\Entity\\TicketUser {$alias}_u1
    JOIN Tuxie\\Bundle\\TuxieBundle\\Entity\\TicketUser {$alias}_u2 WITH {$alias}_u1.ticketId = {$alias}_u2.ticketId
    WHERE {$alias}_u1.userId = :{$alias}_user";

        if($addMyUser === true) {

            $this->where("root.userId IN ($query) OR ({$alias}_u2.userId) ");
        }
        else {

            $this->where("root.userId IN ($query)");
        }

        $this->setParameter("{$alias}_user", $user);
        return $this;
    }
```

So if second parameter in the fuction is on true the filter should use OR statement and give my only actual user. unfortunatelly I am getting syntax error

> [2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 354: Error: Expected
>   =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got ')'
>
> [1/2] QueryException: SELECT root FROM
>   Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\User root WHERE (root.email IS NOT
>   NULL AND (root.userId IN (SELECT ____0_u2.userId FROM
>   Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\TicketUser ____0_u1 JOIN
>   Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\TicketUser ____0_u2 WITH
>   ____0_u1.ticketId = ____0_u2.ticketId WHERE ____0_u1.userId = :____0_user) OR (____0_u2.userId) )) AND root.clientId IS NOT NULL

```
    else {

        $this->where("root.userId IN ($query)");
    }
```

is working correctly. So the problem is in place

```
$this->where("root.userId IN ($query) OR ({$alias}_u2.userId) ");
```

Any ideas on what the correct syntax is for this?

Comment: Hi Gerald, what do you mean by comparing the value with something? Is it possible to simple ... OR (some syntax for my actual user)

Answer (score 1):

`({$alias}_u2.userId)` is not a proper condition for SQL. you need to compare the value with something.

The 'something' depends on your table definition. Some possibilities:

```sql
({$alias}_u2.userId != '') -- for varchar
({$alias}_u2.userId > -1) -- for int
({$alias}_u2.userId NOT NULL) -- for nullable
```

Extensive documentation for available expressions:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html

Comment: now it is 

[2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 339 near '____0_u2.userId': Error: '____0_u2' is used outside the scope of its declaration.  


[1/2] QueryException: SELECT root FROM Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\User root WHERE (root.email IS NOT NULL AND (root.userId IN (SELECT ____0_u2.userId FROM Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\TicketUser ____0_u1
JOIN Tuxie\Bundle\TuxieBundle\Entity\TicketUser ____0_u2 WITH ____0_u1.ticketId = ____0_u2.ticketId
WHERE ____0_u1.userId = :____0_user) OR (____0_u2.userId != '') )) AND root.clientId IS NOT NULL

Comment: That would be a new question, but a quick hint: You are trying to use a column from the subquery outside of it's query. That's not possible.

Comment: @Filip Could you execute $this->getSQL(), and share resulted sql here. We may see the problem more clearly.

Comment: thanks Gerald at the end I change the line to $this->where("root.userId IN ($query OR ({$alias}_u2.userId = '$userId')) ");